# how to create a custom permission salesforce with apex?

Tags: custom-permission

good morning everyone, I'm developing a better way to manage access and permissions with custom permissions, and I'm having some problems, to create one, I need to do a deploy, but I get error 500, could you help me?

```java
public without sharing class CustomPermissionController {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Criar Permissão Personalizada')
    public static void create(List<Request> props) {
        String xmlContent =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
            '<CustomPermission xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">\n' +
            '    <isLicensed>false</isLicensed>\n' +
            '    <label>' + props[0].customPermissionName + '</label>\n' +
            '</CustomPermission>';

        Blob xmlBlob = Blob.valueOf(xmlContent);
        Zippex zippex = new Zippex();
        String fileName = props[0].customPermissionName.trim() + '.customPermission-meta';
        zippex.addFile(fileName + '.xml', xmlBlob, null); 
        Blob zipFile = zippex.getZipArchive();
        System.debug(zipFile);
        String zipFileBase64 = Utils.base64URLencode(zipFile);
        System.debug(zipFileBase64);
        makeRequest(zipFileBase64);
    }

    public static void makeRequest(String zipFileBase64) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/60.0');
        //req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/base64');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setTimeout(100000);
        req.setBody(zipFileBase64);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
    }

    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Name' required=true)
        public String customPermissionName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the correct org base URL, not login.salesforce.com. Have a look at the [URL API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm).

Comment: 18:16:56.225 (484885481)|USER_DEBUG|[30]|DEBUG|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode><faultstring>SOAPAction HTTP header missing</faultstring></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> 

I managed to do it, but I'm getting this xml response, I've already tried adding this empty parameter to the header, add, deploy, I didn't find anything in the documentation, have you seen anything like this?

Comment: I cannot see what header is missing from what you posted. I suggest you raise a separate question with all the details.